# How to manually install SSL certificate on Apache without Cpanel access?

Tags: ssl, cpanel

How to manually install SSL certificate without Cpanel access on Centos 7/Apache? My Cpanel license is expired (simply have no money), so I can't login and can't use WHM API (command line) because API try to read Cpanel license file.

The certificate is already stored on system (issued by Lets Encrypt plugin). But I don't know how to make it effective on my site since Apache config folder is different on Cpanel system. What file should I edit to input my cert address?

Certificate is stored at: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem

Private key is stored at: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem

Note: I use Engintron (Nginx Cpanel plugin), don't know if this change anything. I have root access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to install SSL certificate (by Let's Encrypt) on cPanel directly by running Certbot-Auto command on SSH screen. Certbot-Auto will generate certificate and install it. It is very simple: https://certbot.eff.org/docs/install.html#certbot-auto.

I had to delete the old expired certificates from my **/home/mydomain/ssl** folder to avoid conflict. I don't know how things are inside cPanel cause I still have no license to access. I will renew license soon, but can't stop working on my site just because I have no SSL.